# react-number-format not allowing leading 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, number-formatting, react-number-format

I am using react-number-format.  My users need to be able to enter values such as 0.01.  They cannot do that.  They have to start by entering 1, and then move their cursor to the beginning and then they can enter 0.  They cannot start with 0.  `allowLeadingZeros={true}` does not work.

This my onValueChange and NumberFormat field:

```
const onFTEChange = (values, sourceInfo) => {
    const id = sourceInfo?.event?.target?.id;
    var value = values?.floatValue || 0;
    if (["Labor"].includes(singleSizing?.ExpenseType)) {
        if (id === "1FTE") {
            setSingleSizing({ ...singleSizing, 1FTE: value, Q1Cost: value * blendedRate });
        } else if (id === "2FTE") {
            setSingleSizing({ ...singleSizing, 2FTE: value, Q2Cost: value * blendedRate });
        } else if (id === "3FTE") {
            setSingleSizing({ ...singleSizing, 3FTE: value, Q3Cost: value * blendedRate });
        } else if (id === "4FTE") {
            setSingleSizing({ ...singleSizing, 4FTE: value, Q4Cost: value * blendedRate });
        }
    }
};
...
<NumberFormat
    id="1FTE"
    label={"1 FTE"}
    customInput={TextField}
    isNumericString={true}
    thousandSeparator={true}
    decimalScale={2}
    allowLeadingZeros={true}
    onValueChange={onFTEChange}
    value={singleSizing?.1FTE || ""}
    {...props}
/>
```

Comment: The value is set as `value={singleSizing?.1FTE || ""}`, where/when do you change `singleSizing?.1FTE`? `onFTEChange` changes `Q1FTE` but not `1FTE`.

Comment: This is just a difference in code here in the stack question.  I was removing characters to shorten the question.  In my code, Q1FTE matches in all the right places.  I am not having issues with entering data or saving data.  I just cannot make 0 the first character I enter into `NumberFormat` fields.  I need to be able to do that.

Comment: I have the same problem. 
Did you find the correct way ?

Comment: @AlbertoManuguerra Yes.  For me, this issue was caused by `|| ""` at the end of `value`.  If you are also doing this, then just remove `|| ""` from `value`